how to use the secondary mic as the main mic?
There is a redmi 8a, Root access is available, the lower (main) microphone does not work. The upper microphone (secondary) is working. It only works when making a call or recording a video. You need to somehow change the default microphone to the upper one. (To solder, to repair, to buy a new one, there is no possibility.) help kind people.
Try edit build.prop, add persist.audio.fluence.voicerec=true. Not working
